# button click, adds some text and number to a div. Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, list, css

I really need some help to create this order list. It's the mening that, when you click on the button it adds the text inside the addToList, to the div, so it shows up on the page. It should add the data (name, price), in javascript.
But can't get it to work properly.

```
<html>
 <body>
    <div id="myList">

    </div>

    <button onclick="addToList('donut', '25,-')">add</button>
 </body>
</html>




    <style>
    #myList {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>





    <script>
    function displayListCart() {
        var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
    };



    function addToList(name,price) {
      var itemOrder = {};
      //itemOrder with data
      itemOrder.Name=name;
      itemOrder.Price=price;
      //Add newly created product to our shopping cart 
      listCart.push(itemOrder);
      displayListCart();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried console.log() on each line of your JavaScript to verify the line returns the results you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/o3tf0yne/1/).

I'm not a fan of inline calls to JavaScript functions because it violates separation of concerns, so I've changed the way the event is bound.  This isn't part of your problem, but I'm using this approach:

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myList">
</div>

<button id="btn" data-name="donut" data-price="25,-">add</button>
```

Note:

- I've added the values as data attributes on the button.  You can then
  access them from JavaScript.

---

**JavaScript:**

```
 function displayListCart(listCart) {
   var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
   for (i = 0; i < listCart.length; i++) {
     myList.innerHTML = myList.innerHTML + listCart[i].Name + " : " + listCart[i].Price;
   }
 };


 function addToList(name, price) {
   var itemOrder = {};
   //itemOrder with data
   itemOrder.Name = name;
   //debugging -- check to make sure this returns what you expect
   console.log(itemOrder.Name);
   itemOrder.Price = price;
   //debugging -- check to make sure this returns what you expect
   console.log(itemOrder.Price);
   //Add newly created product to our shopping cart 
  //declare listCart before you use it
   var listCart = [];
   listCart.push(itemOrder);
   //pass listCart to the display function
   displayListCart(listCart);
 }

 function getValues() {
   addToList(myBtn.getAttribute('data-name'), myBtn.getAttribute('data-price'));
 }
 var myBtn = document.getElementById("btn");

 myBtn.addEventListener("click", getValues, false);
```

**Notes:**

- You need to declare listCart before you add objects to it.
- I suspect you intended to pass listCart to the display function so that you can access the objects within it for display.
- You were missing the logic that adds the values to the div.  You need to iterate over the array and access the object properties.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have learn something new and will remember it, for the next time.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if you open the Dev Tools, you will see an error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: listCart is not defined`. So the first thing you need to do is create `listCart` array, like this : `var listCart = [];`

Then you should modify your `displayListCart` function, to display a new div for every item in `listCart`, like this:

```
function displayListCart() {
   var myList = document.getElementById("myList"),
       myListContent = "";
   listCart.forEach(function(cart) {
      myListContent += "<div>" + cart.Name + ": " + cart.Price + "<div>";            
   });
   myList.innerHTML = myListContent;
};
```

[The code example](http://jsbin.com/zocuke/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still new to js, so have much to learn.